# Vagrant NFS folders + Firewall rules

Tags: networking, virtualbox, firewall, nfs, vagrant

I am trying to configure the firewall -via the GUI tool- on 14.04 by adding rules to allow NFS folder sharing with my vagrant box. However this only works when the firewall is disabled as on `vagrant up` it hangs on `default: Mounting NFS shared folders...` while otherwise the folders don't sync. I have tried some of the suggested settings under `Application > NFS` from the dropdown as well as allowing traffic on both ways between the box and the host for the IP of the box and the host as set in the `vagrantfile` but nothing changed.  What rules should I add to make it work?